2sxc mobius forms 6 - turn on feature Custom WebAPIs save in ADAM
I'm using DNN9.13.4, 2sxc 17.09 and Mobius Forms Builder 6. I've added "Contact Form with Files" to the page and when I submit the form, I get the error

An unexpected error occured while sending. Please try again. If it
fails again, please send it by E-Mail.

The admin logs shows the error as "can't save in ADAM - Features 'SaveInAdamApi', 'PublicUploadFiles' not enabled
The form successfully posts the data, just not the files added to the file upload
I've seen some other documentation about turning on features in 2sxc but that was an older version and the module is very different now and I don't see anything in the Mobius module about allowing uploading. Is there a way to turn on "save in ADAM" for a file upload control? Or is this a permissions issue and, if so, what permission has to be set and where?
Also, I have other test apps that can save images to the adam folder.

SaveInAdam is a feature you must turn on explicitly since it does change your security profile.
Go to System Settings (the many-boxes icon). There you should register (so we could inform you if there is a security issue) and then activate the feature.

Thanks. I registered and retrieved the license in features. It said the license was imported. But I'm still getting the SaveInAdam error. Is there another step that I need to take?

I found where I needed to turn on those features locally, and uploads are working now. Thanks, I think the app is great.
